# change string value further on in function

Tags: python

I have a function which declares a string at the start:

```
def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
    current_uarfcn = "10650"
    ran_update_uarfcn = "upd ap" + " " + access_point_id + " " + "uarfcn=" + current_uarfcn 
    //etc
```

Later on in the function, in multiple places, I change the value of `current_uarfcn`.
I then pass `ran_update_uarfcn` to another function. Now  `ran_update_uarfcn` contains the original values set to it. so it will always be `10650` that I am passing.

```
current_uarfcn = "11000"
proc_stdout = ran_cmd(ran_update_uarfcn)
```

Is there any way to update the original string without having to define it every time I want to pass it to a function like I have to below?

```
current_uarfcn = "11000"
ran_update_uarfcn = "upd ap" + " " + access_point_id + " " + "uarfcn=" + current_uarfcn
proc_stdout = ran_cmd(ran_update_uarfcn)
```

This is tedious when you have to do it multiple times. I was hoping the original string could get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an inner function `set_current_uarfcn(value)`

```
current_uarfcn = ""
ran_update_uarfcn = ""

def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
  def set_current_uarfcn(value):
    global current_uarfcn
    global ran_update_uarfcn
    current_uarfcn = value
    ran_update_uarfcn = "upd ap" + " " + access_point_id + " " + "uarfcn=" + current_uarfcn 
  set_current_uarfcn("10650")
  //etc
```

Then later in your function, you can write:

```
set_current_uarfcn("11000")
proc_stdout = ran_cmd(ran_update_uarfcn)
```

Comment: Such a weird error I am getting. It all works apart from if I print `current_uarfcn` after using set. It says: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_uarfcn' referenced before assignment` yet I can print `ran_update_uarfcn` just fine. Both variables are used in exactly the same way!

Comment: For me it's working, I can print both. What is a minimal code that reproduces this error ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to update the string automatically.

However, you could implement the string as a function of `current_uarfcn`:

```
ran_update_uarfcn = lambda x: "upd ap " + access_point_id + " uarfcn=" + x
```

and pass `ran_update_uarfcn(current_uarfcn)`.

Comment: Thanks, the anonymous function is neater than declaring the separate function

Comment: I got `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable` looking for a solution. This is because it is `<function <lambda> at 0x2b1e53b0>
` and not a string when i try to use it then.

Comment: @Paul Well, it's a function of `current_uarfcn` and it only produces the (subscriptable) string, when called as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a string template?

```
def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
    ran_update_uarfcn_tmpl = "upd ap {access_point_id} uarfcn={uarfcn}"
    ran_update_uarfcn = lambda uarfcn: ran_update_uarfcn_tmpl.format(access_point_id=access_point_id, uarfcn=uarfcn)

    current_uarfcn = "10650"
    print ran_update_uarfcn(current_uarfcn)
    current_uarfcn = "11000"
    proc_stdout = ran_cmd(ran_update_uarfcn(current_uarfcn))
```

Or maybe you can refactor this further?

```
def uarfcn_str(method, access_point_id, uarfcn):
    return "{method} ap {apid} uarfcn={uarfcn}".format(
        method=method, apid=access_point_id, uarcfn=uarfcn)

def ran_cmd_update_uarcfn(apid, uarfcn):
    return ran_cmd(uarfcn_str('upd', apid, uarfcn))

def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
    ran_cmd_upd = lambda uarfcn: ran_cmd_update_uarcfn(access_point_id, uarfcn)
    current_uarfcn = "10650"
    proc_stdout = ran_cmd_upd(current_uarfcn)
    current_uarfcn = "10650"
    proc_stdout = ran_cmd_upd(current_uarfcn)
```